# How to print an HashMap by value and not by key with Jquery

Tags: java, jquery, json, jsp, hashmap

That's the code to list the map into a jsp with *jQuery*.

```
function getCustomerMap() {
    $.ajax({
        url: serverUrl + "/getMap",
        success: function (data) {
            var map = JSON.parse(data);
            $.each(map, function (key, value) {
                $('#users').append('<li data-user="' + key + '"><a>' +  value.name + '</a></li>');                    
            });
```

This is how the *HashMap* *JSON* comes to jsp:

[image]

Like you can see, the map is ordered by name.

But this is how the *HashMap* is listed:

[image]

The map is listed from smaller key to biggest!

I would that the map was listed like comes to jsp..

Comment: `HashMap` doesn't have any order. If you wish the entries to be ordered the same way as received, you should probably use a `LinkedHashMap` instead.

Comment: I tried to do this. I replace HashMap with LinkedHashMap, but the method that orders the list gives me this error: **entry has private access in linkedhashmap**

Comment: I converted the HashMap into LinkedHashMap, but the result is the same. The problem is with jQuery

Comment: Do you have any reason not to sort it on the client side?

Comment: @Tap, yes. It is a contact list, and it's logic that is sorted

Comment: Right, but it becomes a plain old javascript object on the client side, and the keys just become object properties.  Their natural sort order is 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6.  That's why they're displayed in that order.  You could add a few lines of javascript to order it by name after the ajax response comes back.

Comment: @Tap, suggestions to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the string representation of the map is received on the client side, it becomes a plain old javascript object, and the keys are its fields.  Their natural sort order is "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6".  This is why it's displayed in that order.  One way to display it the way you want is to convert it to an array of objects (the map values), and sort by name with javascript:

```
function getCustomerMap() {
    $.ajax({
        url: serverUrl + "/getMap",
        success: function (data) {
            var map = JSON.parse(data);
            var arr = new Array();
            for (var key in map)
                arr.push(map[key]); // add the map values to the array

            // sort the array by name
            arr.sort(function(a, b){
                if (a.name < b.name)
                    return -1;
                if (a.name > b.name)
                    return 1;
                return 0;
            });

            // iterate by array index and append the list items.
            // now you use the id field of the objects as your data-user values.
            for (var i in arr)
                $('#users').append('<li data-user="' + arr[i].id + '"><a>' + arr[i].name + '</a></li>');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can I ask you one thing more?